# How to edit a key with Win32::TieRegistry?

Tags: windows, perl, registry, key

I was doing a script with Perl and I came up with the following problem: I have to edit the name of a key in the Windows registry.

I'm using the module [Win32::TieRegistry](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aTieRegistry) and searched at the documentation for any function, but didn't find it. I know that it should be easy, but can't find the way to do that. Any tip?

Thanks!

Comment: (1.) Re-add entry with new key, (2.) Verify succesfull insertion of new key / entry (3.) `delete` the old key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change the name of a key in a hash, but you can copy the value to a new key and delete the old one.

```
$hash{new} = delete $hash{old};
```

This should work the same for a tied hash, assuming the implementation is sane.